# Managing Couchbase buckets dynamically through Java SDK

Tags: couchbase

I would like to know if there's some way to perform functions like listing the existing buckets in a couchbase cluster, creating a new bucket, retrieving cluster information etc. using the Couchbase Java SDK?

I know this can be done through the [REST API](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/REST/rest-cluster-intro.html), but I'm trying to manage the cluster dynamically using Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a `ClusterManager` class accessible through the `Cluster`object's `clusterManager()` method. You'll need the administrative credentials.

Comment: Thank you @simon that helped! How can I check the number of nodes connected to a cluster using the SDK?

Comment: `cluster.clusterManager(adminLogin, adminPass).info().raw().getArray("nodes").size()` should work

Answer (score 0):

To create a new bucket you can use the cluster manager class's insertBucket() method that takes in a BucketSettings object. For example you can create a bucket like this :

....

```
    BucketSettings PrashantSampleBucket = new 
    DefaultBucketSettings.Builder()
            .type(BucketType.COUCHBASE)
            .name("PrashantSampleBucket")
            .password("")
            .quota(2048) // megabytes
            .replicas(1)
            .indexReplicas(true)
            .enableFlush(true)
            .build();
```

....
and now you need to insert your bucket in your cluster this can be done by :

```
    cluster.clusterManager().insertBucket(PrashantSampleBucket);
```